# export products Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql

I would like to export all details of products to import in another Magento platform. I know the easy way is from the following: 
system>under Data Transfer- export> choose entity type: product + Export File Format: CSV + choose all attribute> continue.

but i get all the following coulumes empty in CSV file, why? and How to fix it ? 
name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility, price, pecial_price, special_price_from_date, special_price_to_date, url_key    meta_title, meta_keywords, meta_description base_image, base_image_label    small_image small_image_label, thumbnail_image, thumbnail_image_label,  swatch_image, swatch_image_label, created_at, updated_at, new_from_date new_to_date display_product_options_in, map_price, msrp_price, map_enabled  gift_message_available, custom_design, custom_design_from, custom_design_to custom_layout_update, page_layout, product_options_container, msrp_display_actual_price_type, country_of_manufacture, additional_attributes

Version: Magento 2.1.9

Comment: You said you "choose all attribute". Do you mean to say you're selecting all of the attributes on the export screen?

Comment: do not choose any attribute, it's for ignore.